# Is it possible to set a Postgres array value by specified index disregarding the length?

Tags: arrays, postgresql, jsonb

I have the next JSONB data structure in my `data` column:

```
data = {
  field1,
  field2,
  ...,
  items: [id1, id2, ...id3],
}
```

And there is a necessity to add an item in the `items` array specifying its index.
There can be **several parallel requests to the API, each one providing an ID and its index**, so it's impossible to just replace an old `data` with a new one.
Because in the API code we don't know what is the current number of items.

Help me, please.
How can we handle this situation using Postgres?

For example, it's great to use something like `splice` in the Javascript, when you can set a value by index and fill the rest with `null` values.
But is anything similar possible in Postgres?

What results am I expecting (example):

1. first request, index = 5, array in the db = [null, null, null, null, null, id]
2. second request, index = 2, array in the db = [null, null, id, null, null, id]
3. third request, index = 0, array in the db = [id, null, id, null, null, id]
4. fourth request, index = 3, array in the db = [id, null, id, id, null, id]
5. fifth request, index = 2, array in the db = [id, null, id, id, id, id]
6. sixth request, index = 1, array in the db = [id, id, id, id, id, id]

And so on.

Comment: This would be much easier with a properly normalized model using a one-to-many relationship. Then you simply insert new rows into a table

Comment: What was the value in the database at step zero, before you had done any of this?

Comment: @jjanes it's just `data: { files: [] }`

Comment: So jsonb_set probably won't work, as it won't null-pad the array out to the desired length.  You could try to create your own alternative to jsonb_set which does do null-padding.  If I needed to do that, I would probably implement it in pl/perl rather than trying to use SQL or PL/pgSQL (although I suspect both are possible).  Or I would do it in the client like the 2nd part of my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There can be several parallel requests to the API, each one providing an ID and its index, so it's impossible to just replace an old data with a new one.

That is the only thing that **is** possible in PostgreSQL. Individual components of JSONB cannot be edited in place, you have to retrieve the old JSONB value, modify it, and replace it with the new one.

You can probably do what you want with [jsonb_set](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html).

```
update mytable set myjsonb=jsonb_set(myjsonb,'{items,3}','"id3"') where myid=6
```

But this probably won't do what you want if the index you are trying to set is off the end of the existing array by more than one value.

If you want to do the manipulations in the client language, you will have to lock the row so no one else with the intention of writing can read the soon-to-be stale value and think they can work with it.

```
BEGIN;
select myjsonb from mytable where myid=6 for update;
<do stuff here in the client>
update mytable set myjsonb=:newvalue where myid=6;
COMMIT;
```